# Android Studio adding external JAR to the project

Tags: gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying all I can to add an external JAR file to my project but I just can't do it. Here's what I'm doing atm:

- Copying JAR to libs folder
- Hitting "Add as library" and selecting jar package option
- Modifying build.gradle to include the new jar, I'm doing it simply like this:

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }

Yet I'm still getting some weird error on Pre Dex phase:

```
Android Pre Dex: [StartAppUnifiedSDK-3.0.2.jar] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Android Pre Dex: [StartAppUnifiedSDK-3.0.2.jar] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: could you paste the output from the command "gradle build --stacktrace" ?

Answer (score 0):

the error message format shows that you are not using Gradle to build. You either loaded the eclipse project file (.classpath/.project) or had some existing iml files.

This means changes to build.gradle will have no effect since Studio uses the IntelliJ internal builders instead.

You need to import your build.gradle file instead to create a new Studio project.